# Ошибка выполнения функции GetMainWindow FlaUI C#

Tags: c#, автоматизация, uiautomation

я использую библиотеку FlaUI для автоматизации ПК приложения.

Я получил ошибку при попытке запустить код, чтобы взять окно запущенной программы. Ошибка: не удалось найти процесс с идентификатором: ***'

Подробности ошибки.

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Could not find process with id: 13536
  Source=FlaUI.Core
  StackTrace:
   at FlaUI.Core.Application.FindProcess(Int32 processId)
   at FlaUI.Core.Application.<WaitWhileMainHandleIsMissing>b__33_0()
   at FlaUI.Core.Tools.Retry.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<WhileTrue>b__0()
   at FlaUI.Core.Tools.Retry.While[T](Func`1 retryMethod, Func`2 checkMethod, Nullable`1 timeout, Nullable`1 interval, Boolean throwOnTimeout, Boolean ignoreException, String timeoutMessage, Boolean lastValueOnTimeout, T defaultOnTimeout)
   at FlaUI.Core.Application.WaitWhileMainHandleIsMissing(Nullable`1 waitTimeout)
   at FlaUI.Core.Application.GetMainWindow(AutomationBase automation, Nullable`1 waitTimeout)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\jekug\source\repos\FlaUI test\FlaUI test\Program.cs:line 10

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentException: Process with an Id of 13536 is not running.
```

Что может быть не так и есть ли другие способы взять окно во FlaUI?

Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не пользовалась подобной библиотекой, почитала документацию и в примере кода написано следующие // Note: Works only pre-Windows 8 with the legacy calculator
var app = FlaUI.Core.Application.Launch("calc.exe"); т.е работает только до Win 8

Comment: Так было написано конкретно за программу calc.exe , попробуйте запустить другую программу

Comment: Вот пример, который я нашла https://prnt.sc/kaQ_EGwSC1Zl

Comment: @КатяАппазова с другими программами так же. На другом пк тоже с вин10 функция работает, но не со всеми программами. Вы пользуетесь другой библиотекой для автоматизации?

Comment: `Could not find process with id: 13536` ну а у вас есть этот процесс?

Comment: @tym32167 не знаю. Как я могу это проверить? При каждом выполнении номер процесса отличается

Comment: Калькулятор WinRT процесс, а ваша библиотека вероятно совместима только с Win32 приложениями.